# Generating SQL queries with full table data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to generate SQL queries with all table records, using SQL Server Management Studio Express. I know how to generate queries for creating database itself, and full database structure: tables, views and stored procedures. Is it possible to make queries with all table content?

Comment: When you say all table content do you mean the fields and datatypes, essentially schematic information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en) to script your data (along with scripts for schema)

This works with 2005 and can be used to generate scripts for schema only, data or both.

It generates a single SQL script file which can be used to recreate the contents of a database by manually executing the script on a target server.

The pre-requisite for Database Publishing Wizard is .NET 2.0 Framework, SQL Server 2005 Management Objects (SMO is included for use with SQL Express)